# JS Request getting called twice in a row

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, railstutorial.org

I'm working on the Ruby on Rails Tutorial. I have the asynchronous follow buttons working. Interestingly, each of the javascript calls is getting called twice in a row when I click the button. Any thoughts on how I make it only send one request? Here is my log

```
Started POST "/tag_user_relationships/123" for
127.0.0.1 at 2011-06-13 21:18:59 -0700   Processing by TagUserRelationshipsController#destroy as JS   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"goedvibRxKtDRiAufp1ThWJP0rRBU2cMH2xp7qodKws=", "commit"=>"Unfollow", "id"=>"123"}   User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1   TagUserRelationship Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `tag_user_relationships`.* FROM `tag_user_relationships` WHERE `tag_user_relationships`.`id` = 123 LIMIT 1   Tag Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `tags`.* FROM `tags` WHERE `tags`.`id`
= 9 LIMIT 1   TagUserRelationship Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `tag_user_relationships`.* FROM `tag_user_relationships` WHERE `tag_user_relationships`.`tag_id` = 9 AND (`tag_user_relationships`.user_id
= 2) LIMIT 1   SQL (0.1ms)  BEGIN   AREL (0.2ms)  DELETE FROM `tag_user_relationships` WHERE `tag_user_relationships`.`id` = 123   SQL (0.4ms)  COMMIT   SQL (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` INNER JOIN `tag_user_relationships` ON `users`.id = `tag_user_relationships`.user_id WHERE ((`tag_user_relationships`.tag_id = 9))   SQL (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `tags` INNER JOIN `tag_user_relationships` ON `tags`.id
= `tag_user_relationships`.tag_id WHERE ((`tag_user_relationships`.user_id = 2)) Rendered tag_user_relationships/_form.js.erb (15.8ms) Rendered tags/_follow.html.erb (2.1ms) Rendered tag_user_relationships/destroy.js.erb (20.3ms) Completed 200 OK in 138ms (Views: 28.1ms | ActiveRecord: 2.3ms)


Started POST "/tag_user_relationships/123" for
127.0.0.1 at 2011-06-13 21:18:59 -0700   Processing by TagUserRelationshipsController#destroy as JS   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"goedvibRxKtDRiAufp1ThWJP0rRBU2cMH2xp7qodKws=", "id"=>"123"}   User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1   TagUserRelationship Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `tag_user_relationships`.* FROM `tag_user_relationships` WHERE `tag_user_relationships`.`id` = 123 LIMIT 1 Completed 404 Not Found in 70ms

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find TagUserRelationship with ID=123): app/controllers/tag_user_relationships_controller.rb:14:in `destroy'

Rendered /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@rails3tutorial/gems/actionpack-3.0.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.0ms) Rendered /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@rails3tutorial/gems/actionpack-3.0.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (153.6ms) Rendered /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@rails3tutorial/gems/actionpack-3.0.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (160.2ms)
```

And here is my view

```
$("#<%= "follower_info#{@tag.id}" %>").html("<%=escape_javascript(pluralize(@tag.followers.count,'follower'))%>");     
var link = $('<a>').attr('href',"<%=user_tags_path(current_user) %>").text("<%= escape_javascript(pluralize(current_user.beats.count,'tag')) %>");
$("#<%= "user#{current_user.id}_following" %>").html(link); $("#<%= "follow_form#{@tag.id}" %>").html("<%= escape_javascript("#{render('tags/unfollow', :tag => @tag)}").html_safe %>");
```

And my controller

```
  def create
    @tag = Tag.find(params[:tag_user_relationship][:tag_id])
    current_user.follow_tag!(@tag)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @tag }
      format.js
    end   
  end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this same issue recently. Is there any chance that you installed the ajax gem and also included the jquery code in the Javascripts folder? If so, the calls will be made twice.

Comment: I don't think I installed an ajax gem. Did you add it to your gemfile? I definitely have jquery code.

Comment: any chance you included the jquery code twice in your javascripys folder?

Comment: bingo - I had jquery.min and jquery_ujs